# Is it possible to write data to a locally json file with nothing but angular?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to write data to a json file after hitting "Submit" on an html formly-form using only angular, but nothing is happening. I know I can read a json file using angular but not sure on creating files.
onSubmit() in controller:

```
function onSubmit() {
    $scope.save = function() {
        $http.post('./temp/sample_data.json', JSON.stringify($scope.model)).then(function(data) {
            $scope.msg = 'Data saved';
        });
    };
};
```

html:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <formly-form model="model" fields="fields"></formly-form><br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The sample_data.json isn't created and if I create an empty file it does not fill up with the data as well. The $scope.model defenitly contains data. 
If anyone can help, it will be very appreciated.
Thanks, Alon.

Comment: It's totally impossible cause you don't have such permission in client-side

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is it possible to write data to a locally json file with nothing but angular?

No. Even if you're running the page from the local file system (e.g., `file://myfile.html`) or from a local webserver (e.g., `http://localhost/myfile.html` or `http://host-on-my-intranet/myfile.html`), you still have no means of directly writing to a file from browser-hosted JavaScript code.

Two choices:

1. Send it to something (e.g., a server) that can write it out, or
2. Provide it as a `data:` URI (if feasible in your case) that the user can right-click and choose "save as..."

   Here's how you create a `data:` URI for some JSON text:

   ```
   var uri = "data:application/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(theJSON);
   ```

**Full Example** of #2:

```js
var theData = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var theJSON = JSON.stringify(theData);
var uri = "data:application/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(theJSON);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = uri;
a.innerHTML = "Right-click and choose 'save as...'";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Okay got it. Tried the second choice and worked well. Anyway a future server will be involved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No.

Angular runs client side.

If you want to write data to the server (even one on the same computer as the browser) then you need server side code to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't access the local filesystem (directly) from Javascript.  This is enforced for security reasons (and makes sense when you think about it!).

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is not possible you could try another route. Your $scope.save was not being invoked by the way, only assigned.

```
$scope.save = function() {
  localStorage.model = JSON.stringify($scope.model);
};
function onSubmit() {
  $scope.save();
  $scope.msg = 'saved';
};
```

To get your model back do this on init:

```
if (localStorage.model)
  $scope.model = JSON.parse(localStorage.model);
```

Comment: localStorage hardly qualifies as a json file

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is not known what the specific requirement is. The questioner is new to web development and is giving a possible path of reasoning that is not working based on the limitations of the current technology. If you were to give a possible alternative solution, this is considered more effort than merely stating the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The following code adds a download button for a JSON object.

**Note:** wrapping a button with an anchor tag is not recommended for HTML 5 yet it works in Chrome which is all I needed. YMMV.

HTML:

```html
<a download="my-json-object.json" [href]="dataUri">
  <button>Download</button>
</a>
```

Typescript:

```js
  get dataUri(): SafeUrl {
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(this.dataSource);
    const uri = 'data:application/json;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(jsonData);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(uri);
  }
```

Comment: This is all I needed. Gold!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm digging in the past here, but the question is still relevant, judging by me looking for it today.

The accepted answer is the right one, I just want to add this implementation that works in Angular 15, from within a button click handler, without adding an actual  element to the DOM and also sets the name of the file for download. It's dealing with a .csv file, but it is the same for .json too.

```js
onExportButtonClick() {
  // Render the CSV file content
  let textResult = 'column1,column2,column3\n';
  textResult += ... generate text content ...

  // Create a blob from the CSV file content
  const blob = new Blob([textResult], { type: 'text/csv' });

  // Create a link to the blob
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = 'generated_filename.csv';
  link.click();
}
```

And in the template (with Angular Material):

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        color="primary" (click)="onExportButtonClick()">
  <mat-icon>save_alt</mat-icon>
  Export
</button>
```

Clicking on this button initiates a download of the generated file.