# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'Component ' ? file.json Angular 6

Tags: json, typescript, angular6, fs

[import fs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3pOW.png)

[fs = requier('fs')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bftbN.png)

[fs index.d.ts I can see fs library but I can't use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSio.png)

[Error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkmwh.png)

my problem if I write require cmd error 
also, after installed fs of npm install fs.

same error after install or before install fs

Comment: fs is a module that is part of NodeJS. NodeJS is server-side. Angular is a framework for creating front-end applications. Check this out: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5324

Comment: Okay how solve my problem  , I wanna write json file

Comment: I believe this question would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288087/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-a-locally-json-file-with-nothing-but-angular It's not possible to write static files to the file system using client-side code. You'll have to choose an alternative method.

Comment: Thank you , but can you tell me how to save data directly such as saveAs(ex.json);

Comment: I am seen ur link last 3 hour but is give me link I wanna directly to json file , I'm confused sry .

Comment: You can't write directly to a json file. That stack overflow answer explains the other options.

Comment: I have been searched of 4 days for your answer thanks you

Comment: can you tell me , other options ?

Comment: I would like to explain the other options to you, but that other answer already explains them in great detail. This is a duplicate to that question. I would not be able to explain it any better.

Comment: hahhaaha hahahah ty.

Comment: hahahahahah I do that and save data directly to json file + dynamically

Comment: You don't have more experience in Node.js with Angular 6 you need course to learn of me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. You were trying to use Node file system api to write to a json file, but in your answer, you are downloading a file that you received from your server. These are not the same things.

Comment: It seems I missed your comment about wanting to save a file as json. Sorry about that. However, I'm not sure that you really want to download the file onto the client machine, unless you expect the client to use the data for something.

Comment: No, problem pro, I'm just kidding! :D