# Get data from file and write to file

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angularJS to write data to file in local folder? I managed to get data from the file and now i want to write something.

I get data from `data.json`, but `order.txt` is `404 (Not Found)` or `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.constant("dataUrl", "data.json")
.constant("orderUrl", "order.txt")
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $location,
    dataUrl, orderUrl, cart) {

    $scope.data = {
    };

    $http.get(dataUrl)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data.products = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });

    $scope.sendOrder = function (shippingDetails) {
        var order = angular.copy(shippingDetails)
        order.products = cart.getProducts();

        $http.post(orderUrl, order)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data.orderId = data.id;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.data.orderError = error;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is not possible. Some alternatives suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288087/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-a-locally-json-file-with-nothing-but-angular

Comment: That makes sens. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it by using `**blob**`

```
$scope.data = {
    };

$scope.writeFile = function () {
    $scope.data = angular.toJson($filter('filter')($scope.sendOrder));
};
}]);

var blob = new Blob([scope.writeFile],{
type: "application/json;charset=utf-8;"
});
downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Kindly go through [that](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) too.

Hope it helps.
Thanks!